# CSS & SASS Nav Issue

Tags: html, css, sass, navigation, nav

I've been using Sass and CSS in HTML to create a Nav Bar for a website I'm trying to create, but only the first item of the Nav bar is showing and its aligned to the left. I'm fairly new to coding , so it could be something very basic, but I'm trying to find a way to have a responsive working navigation bar. My HTML has JavaScript in it as I'm using Github.io to implement my website. I've also convert my sass to css via ruby. Does anyone have any ideas what I've done wrong?

[As you can see in the picture, only the about me side is showing in the Navigation bar. the rest of the bar is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxTyZ.jpg)

Thanks again for everyone's help in advance. This site has been a huge help to learning more about coding, so again, thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="Clark Fennell">
    <meta name="description" content="Clark Fennell's Website">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesass.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/.sass-cash/f438d035db857854fbdbe4096cf1f690c6912d06/style.sassc">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bottstrapcdn.com/bottstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css"><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bottstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/JS/mywebjscript.js">
    </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<Title>Clark Fennell's Website</title>
</head>
<header>
<div class="title">
        <p class="heading">CLARK FENNELL</p>
        <p class="heading2">WEBSITE</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
            count = 0;
            wordsArray = ["UX/UI DESIGNER", "FRONT-END DEVELOPER", "WEB DESIGNER", "SOFTWARE DEVELOPER"];
            setInterval(function () {
              count++;
              $("#word").fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400).addClass("small-heading");
              });
            }, 2000);
          });
        </script>
    <div id="word" class="small-heading">UX/UI DESIGNER</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#content-reveal').hide();
  $('#aboutme').click( function() {
      $('#content-reveal').fadeOut( 500, function() {
          $('#content-reveal').html( '<div class="maindiv"><h2>ABOUT ME</h2><br><p>Age: 29<br>Location: Leeds<br><br>I am a developer specialising in HTML, CSS, JAVA, JaveScript, SQL, Command Line, Ruby and many more.<br><br>I am also well equpit at using Adobe programs, such as, PhotoShop, Dreamweaver, Illistrator, InDesign, and other software as well.<br><br>I like to board and video games, watching indepentdant professional wrestling & a nice cup of tea.</p></div>' );
          $('#content-reveal').fadeIn( 500 );
      } );
  } );
  $('#myhtmlcss').click( function() {
      $('#content-reveal').fadeOut( 500, function() {
          $('#content-reveal').html( '<div class="maindiv"><h2>HTML & CSS</h2><br><p>This site is just one example of my HTML, CSS & SCSS skills. The code for this website, plus plenty of other examples, are on my <a href="https://www.github.com/clarkfennell">GITHUB</a>.</p></div>' );
          $('#content-reveal').fadeIn( 500 );
      } );
  } );
  $('#myjscript').click( function() {
      $('#content-reveal').fadeOut( 500, function() {
          $('#content-reveal').html( '<div class="maindiv"><h2>JAVASCRIPT</h2><br><p>Below is a a Random Colour Generator created with JavaScript code. The code for this is located on my <a href="Https://github.com/clarkfennell/Random-Color-Generator-React-JS-Example">GITHUB</a></p><p>For more JavaScript, JQuery and AngularJS, please visit my <a href="https://www.github.com/clarkfennell">GITHUB</a>.</p></div>' );
          $('#content-reveal').fadeIn( 500 );
      } );
  } );
  $('#mycv').click( function() {
      $('#content-reveal').fadeOut( 500, function() {
          $('#content-reveal').html( '<div class="maindiv"><h2>MY CV</h2><br><img src="/images/NEWCVClarkFennell.jpg"></div>' );
          $('#content-reveal').fadeIn( 500 );
      } );
  } );
  $('#mycv').click( function() {
      $('#content-reveal').fadeOut( 500, function() {
          $('#content-reveal').html( '<div class="maindiv"><h2>CONTACT</h2></div>' );
          $('#content-reveal').fadeIn( 500 );
      } );
  } );
} );
</script>
<ul class="PrimaryNav with-indicator">
  <li class="Nav-item" id="aboutme">ABOUT ME</li>
  <li class="Nav-item" id="myhtmlcss">HTML & CSS</li>
  <li class="Nav-item is-active" id="myjscript">JAVASCRIPT</li>
  <li class="Nav-item" id="mycv">MY CV</li>
  <li class="Nav-item" id="contactme">CONTACT</li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
</body>
```

Here is the SASS:

```
$menu-items: 5
$width: (100/$menu-items) * 1%

$background-color: #121212
$indicator-color: #363151

.PrimaryNav
  list-style: none
  margin: 50px auto
  max-width: 720px
  padding: 0
  width: 100%


.Nav-item
  background: #363151
  display: block
  float: left
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  text-align: center
  width: $width


  &:first-child
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px


  &:last-child
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0


  &.is-active a
    color: $indicator-color


  a
    color: $background-color
    display: block
    padding-top: 20px
    padding-bottom: 20px
    text-decoration: none

    &:hover
      color: $indicator-color



.with-indicator
  position: relative

.Nav-item:last-child
  &:before, &:after
    content: ''
    display: block
    position: absolute


  &:before
    width: 0
    height: 0
    border: 6px solid transparent
    border-top-color: $color-indicator
    top: 0
    left: 12.5%
    margin-left: -3px


  &:after
    width: $width
    background: $indicator-color
    top: -6px
    bottom: -6px
    left: 0
    z-index: -1



$menu-items: 5
$menu-items-loop-offset: $menu-items - 1
$width: (100/$menu-items) * 1%

.with-indicator
  @for $i from 1 through $menu-items-loop-offset
    .Nav-item:nth-child(#{$i}).is-active ~ .Nav-item:last-child:after
      left:($width*$i)-$width
    .Nav-item:nth-child(#{$i}).is-active ~ .Nav-item:last-child:before
      left:($width*$i)+($width/2)-$width



  @for $i from 1 through $menu-items-loop-offset
    .Nav-item:nth-child(#{$i}):hover ~ .Nav-item:last-child:after
      left:($width*$i)-$width !important
    .Nav-item:nth-child(#{$i}):hover ~ .Nav-item:last-child:before
      left:($width*$i)+($width/2)-$width !important


.Nav-item
    &:last-child
      &:hover, &.is-active
        &:before
          left: (100%-$width)+($width/2) !important
        &:after
          left: 100%-$width !important
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/*RESET*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent;} body {line-height: 1;}ol, ul{list-style:none;} blockquote, q{quotes:none;} blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after{content:'';content:none;} :focus{outline:0;} ins{text-decoration:none;} del{text-decoration:line-through;} table{border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}

/*MAIN*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "Etna";
    src:url("/Fonts/enta.eot");
    src:url("/Fonts/enta.otf") format("opentype"),
            url("/Fonts/etna.woff") format("woff"),
            url("/Fonts/etna.svg") format("svg"),
            url("/Fonts/etna.ttf") format("ttf");
}

@import url('https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade|Titllium+Web');

html, body {
    background-color: #EEEAE3;
    font-family: 'Titllium Web', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
        font-size: 1.15em;
        color: #24282B;
        font-family: 'Etna', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: left;
}

p {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #24282B;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Titllium Web', sans-serif;
}

.heading {
    font-family:'Etna', San-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #363151;
    font-size: 3.50em;
}

.heading2 {
    font-family:'Etna', San-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #363151;
    font-size: 1.70em;
}

.small-heading {
    font-family:'Etna', San-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #363151;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.copywrite {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    opacity: 0.25:
}

#wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    align-items: center;
}

#aboutme {background-color: #EEEAE3;}
#myhtmlcss {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
#myjscript {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
#mycv {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
#contactme {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
```

Thanks again

Comment: what's your expected? do you have an image or more text to describe it?

Comment: yes I'm trying to make a dynamic navigation bar, that uses JavaScript/jQuery to fade different divs in and out on top of each other. I've managed to get the divs to work with jQuery, but the Navigation is only showing the first part of it (the "about me" navigation button only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you hide other nav-item by Css

```
#myhtmlcss {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
#myjscript {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
#mycv {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
#contactme {background-color: #EEEAE3; display: none;}
```

if you want to show them you can replace to

```
#myhtmlcss {background-color: #EEEAE3;}
#myjscript {background-color: #EEEAE3;}
#mycv {background-color: #EEEAE3;}
#contactme {background-color: #EEEAE3;}
```